Is there a way to default a Kubernetes variable that is read from a secret, if the secret is not present
I am creating a Kubernetes deployment as follows. Is there a way to default the value of the variable if the secret is not existing? This is a situation where the secret may not be present in certain environments for some time.
for instance I want the SERVICE_MANAGER_CLIENTID to have a value of "" if the secret is not present.

            - name: SERVICE_MANAGER_CLIENTID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: service-manager-subaccount-key
                  key: clientid


Does How to mark secret as optional in kubernetes? answer your question?  If the value is optional: true then the variable won't be present, but the Pod will still start, and $SERVICE_MANAGER_CLIENTID will expand to an empty string in a shell.

@DavidMaze Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.
